Autofill(filter) layers for a batch buffer processing using expression builder belonging to a "Group" in layers panel
I have a grouped ~20 vector layers named as "GroupedLayers". I want to use expression builder to autofill the inputs to batch processing. Otherwise I have to manually add layers one by one.

How can I access and filter layers based on groups using expression builder?

Select from Open Layers option

I see it's good work around. However, in my case I have different layers with same names i.e. LayerA in Group1 and another LayerA in Group2 and I only want to select layers of Group1. So, if there is way to access layers in a particular group that would solve problem.

Layer groups can't be accessed with QGIS expressions, as far as I know.

Are you sure? Can you please share some reference so that I may accept it as answer.
